# Javascript not executing after .then

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to put recaptcha v3 on a form but inserting the token into a hidden input field doesn't work - on the first submission.

Here is the code that I doctored a little.  I added an alert and stopped the sumbit to see what's happening.  This code is in a separate bundle.js file.

```
var form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');
var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('secret_key', {
      action: 'my_action'
    }).then(function(token) {
      document.getElementById('tokenField').value = token;
      alert('token is; ' + token); // inserted for troubleshooting
    });
  });
  removeMessageBox();
  validation();
  var alerts = document.querySelectorAll('.alert-text');
  if (alerts.length == 0) {
    // document.forms['contact-form'].submit(); 
  }
});
```

With this code as written, the alert shows a valid token but tokenField has no value. tokenField gets the token AFTER you press OK on the alert.  What is the problem???  I have tried everything.

If you take out the alert and uncomment submit, tokenField is empty on submission.

Note that this script also calls `validation()` and `removeMessageBox()`, which removes validation error messages.

If validation() stops the submission for some reason, you can fix the problem, submit again and tokenField gets it value and everything works great - the second time.

Comment: Everything starting with `removeMessageBox()` doesn't wait for the recaptcha.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the field is being set inside of a callback, while the other functions are running in the main function. You can either put all of the code into the callback function for the `.then` function, or use an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

#### Callback

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('secret_key', {
      action: 'my_action'
    }).then(function(token) {
      document.getElementById('tokenField').value = token;
      
      removeMessageBox();
      validation();
      var alerts = document.querySelectorAll('.alert-text');
      if (alerts.length == 0) {
        // document.forms['contact-form'].submit(); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

#### Async

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(async function() {
    const token = await grecaptcha.execute('secret_key', {
      action: 'my_action'
    });

    document.getElementById('tokenField').value = token;

    removeMessageBox();
    validation();
    var alerts = document.querySelectorAll('.alert-text');
    if (alerts.length == 0) {
      // document.forms['contact-form'].submit(); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I used the Callback and it works like a champ!  Thank you so much. I knew it had to be some kind of a simple newby mistake. Thanks again. .